# How to install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I need to know how to install Google Chrome and how to use terminal on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/
2. Click Download and a small window will pop up with some download options.

   [image]
3. Select anyone option from first and second depending on your system.
4. Open the downloaded file. It will land you to Ubuntu Software Center
5. Click on Install.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html just download it and run deb and make sure that you have the right version 32 or 64 bit. Once that is done it will open Ubuntu software center and you click install then once it is done you look to see if it is installed if not then it is ether not done or having an issue

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: How was that a -1 answer?

Answer (score -2):

On command line

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

Comment: Did you check that this is available indeed for 14.04?

Comment: thank you ,is it the only thing to write in terminal ?

Comment: No, you also need to add the google PPA. Check the question that is suggested as a duplicate, second answer.